# Is it possible to open an external page within reveal modal?

Tags: zurb-foundation, reveal.js

As my title introduces you, my question is, is it possible to open a page within a foundation's reveal modal (foundation 3)? like for example google.com or even a subpage from the same website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

```
<a href="http://some-url" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
Click Me For A Modal
```

This will load content from the href in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal" data-reveal></div>

<script>
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('#myModal') != -1) {
        $('#myModal').foundation("open");
    }
</script>
```